# actionscript-3 flash, keyboard event key_up/ key_down jumping

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, event-handling, keyboard-events, event-listener

I am making a simple game in as3, with a character that can walk right-left and jump.
I made event listeners for the keys and also added a jumping sound. The right-left movement is ok.
When I press the space key, the char jumps, the sound effect plays, as it should. But if the key stays pressed, then these actions keep happening until I release it. So the char stays on the air and the jumping sound plays again and again.

Is there some way to make the space press function do stuff only when I touch it? At the moment I have setKey and UnSetKey functions that work the same way for every key. This is useful for the right-left, so it can keep moving while key stays pressed but I don't want the same for the jump.
Any help is appreciated; I can post that part of the code if you need me to.

Comment: Add some checks to the event handlers. Once jump animation is playing, skip processing SPACE key.

Comment: Thank you @Organis! I have been researching this cause I haven't used checks before. The best outcome I could get so far was my character jumping up and down if the SPACE key is continuously pressed, by adding the check after the jump. Why would it keep jumping up? I am not sure I understand how this works yet.

Comment: The **KEY_DOWN** is dispatched not only at the moment the user actually presses the key, but also repeatedly several times a second while key is pressed. Exactly like you press "a" in this comment editor and get "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" eventually until you release the key. So, when your jump animation is complete, your code receives the next SPACE event and jumps again. If you want user to actually release SPACE before the next jump, you need to set some **Boolean** flag on SPACE pressed and skip all next SPACEs unless it is unset. Then, unset it on **KEY_UP** event with SPACE **keyCode**.